# Running rspec inside gvim

Tags: vim, rspec

Running `rspec` from inside `gvim` give this weird output:

[image]

Has anyone an idea from where came the issue?
Note: running `rspec` from `vim` works as expected, the problem is specefic to `gvim`, I tried changing the font but nothing.

Using vim:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use GVIM, there's only a very primitive terminal emulation for external commands. This is okay for capturing output, but it doesn't understand the ANSI escape sequences to output different colors and other fancy stuff. That's the gibberish you see.

First, drop off the `--color` argument to `rspec` that presumably instructs the command to use color output. That should at least reduce the gibberish. If there's still some, prefixing `:! TERM=dumb spring rspec ...` might help.

Comment: Tried what you suggested, the output is the same.

Comment: Maybe you need a `--no-color` to override any defaults?

Comment: Awesome! it worked, I had `--color` in my `.rspec` file.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using [Dispatch.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) to run you test. Dispatch's main feature running task asynchronous and then once done you can see the results in the quickfix window via `:Copen`. From the documentation you just run the following:

```
:Dispatch rspec %
```

If you decide to not use dispatch.vim I would at least try and use `:make` so that you can take advantage of the quickfix list. Just do `:compiler rspec` to setup `:make` for using rspec.

Another option maybe using `col -bp` to remove some control characters. e.g. `!rspec foo | col -bp`

For more help see:

```
:h quickfix
:h :copen
:h :make
:h :compiler
```